Why do we need phasors for analysing signals and systems?
Phasor includes a real part as well as an imaginary part, in real domain the intuition is more clear, i.e we can use vectors instead to represent things, but to imagine a signal in a complex domain makes it a bit unintuitive for me.
To be more clear, playing with real numbers is more clear to us, but when it comes to complex domain things start to become a bit ambiguous, the reason is that imaginary part. I can't see the relation of using √-1 with real life signals and systems.
We do this kind of stuff while representing a signal using a Fourier series, for now I have been taught only two methods to represent a signal using Fourier series, first is the trigonometric series which is basically simple and isn't that hard to imagine what's happening. And the second one is by using the phasors which seems unintuitive.
My confusion is that are we doing this to just represent the signals and systems or is there really something imaginary stuff happening there (which is unlikely)?

why do we need phasors? We don't NEED them, but once you understand them, they make a lot of things much simpler.

The "imaginary" part is the Y-axis of the rectangular (X-Y) form of the phasor, which can also be represented in polar form. Instead of saying, for example, "8X+3Y", we just write it as "8+3j". You'll go back and forth a lot because it's easier to add phasors in rectangular form and multiply them in polar. In polar form, j is the quantity that has magnitude 1 and phase angle +90 degrees - it just means a phase shift of +90.

There's no imaginary stuff happening.
You can freely use any method for representing a vector with magnitude (i.e. length) and phase (i.e. direction), but that's the exact same thing as giving the same point in coordinates on XY or complex number plane.
It's just the same spot on the XY plane but you have two different methods of giving the coordinates as distance/angle pair or X/Y coordinate pair.
It just makes some things easier to use one coordinate system over another depending on what you want to do with the result. For example, comparing how much phase difference a circuit causes on your input sine wave is natural in angles, assuming some frequency of interest, like mains frequency circuit or some RF system.
In some other cases, you might need to use the X/Y or Re/Im coordinate system to make calculations easier, such as ignoring real resistance while bringing imaginary reactance into balance by making it zero.
So they are two different views of same thing.
The phasor viewpoint is simple because it allows you to go through amplitude and phase angle at various frequencies to build a Bode plot of the system.


when it comes to complex domain things start to become a bit ambiguous, the reason is that imaginary part.

Don't think of the phasor as being a real part and an imaginary part. Think of it as a magnitude and a phase. The magnitude and phase encode the magnitude and phase of the sinusoidal signal.

I can't see the relation of using √-1 with real life signals and systems.

The relation comes from Euler's Identity:
$$e^{j\theta} = \cos\theta + j\sin\theta$$
From this you can work out how a phasor (\$Ae^{j\phi}\$) allows you to track the time-domain sinusoid if you multiply by \$e^{j\omega t}\$
$$\begin{aligned}Ae^{j\phi}e^{j\omega t} &= Ae^{j(\omega t + \phi)} \\
                 &=A\left(\cos(\omega t + \phi)+j\sin(\omega t + \phi)\right)
  \end{aligned}$$
